# Requesting something to be done for me in cantonese

Tags: word-requests

How do you request something to be done for myself in cantonese?

For example: can you ask him (to get playing cards) for me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First you say "would you please", which is "唔該"(please/ excuse me- *more colloquial*) or "請你" (would you please- *more literary*); you can even say "唔該" and "請你" together and say "唔該請你" (excuse me, would you please)
- then you say "help me/ for me", which is "幫我" or "同我"
- then you state your request.

For example: "打開度門" (open the door)

The whole sentence would be:

"唔該幫我打開度門" or  "請你同我打開度門"

*You can substitute "打開度門" with any request*

*To be extra polite you can replace "請你" with "麻煩你/ 勞煩你" (trouble yourself)*

*If it was a command, you can just state your request directly. e,g. "打開度門!" or simply "開門!"*

Cantonese use final particle much more often than Mandarin. The most native way to say it, is "唔該幫我打開度門吖" -- using final particle '吖' to soften the tone and make it sound less demanding